# How to fetch all sports by partial search from Wikidata, retrieve first image and languages

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I've been trying for 2 days with SPARQL and Wikidata and went through all examples. I need help figuring out a complicated query that I haven't found an example close to my needs.

The idea is to search for sports, get the first image (if one is found). and retrieve the labels in all languages. Below I achieved a small part but here are the problems.

1. with this query, I'm able to get basketball but not football, I cannot figure out how to make search with subclass as footbal is a subclass of type of sports, I thought I had it working right but it doesn't return football.
2. when I add to fetch image (tried with optional), it returns "bodybuilding" in 2 rows because there are 2 images for boxing, is there a way to get the first one row with first image only. I tried distinct and didn't get far with it.
3. In this case I'm searching in English but would like to get back labels in all languages.

The perfect result out of this would be 10 rows where each row would be 1 sport starting with "bo", first image and labels in all languages, I understand that it might be a tall order so maybe languages would have to be requested in another query and if so, how?

```
#NOT WORKING AS EXPECTED/Need Help 
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?label WHERE {         
   ?item wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q31629.       
   ?item rdfs:label ?label.          
FILTER((LANG(?label)) = "en")        
FILTER(STRSTARTS(lcase(?label), lcase("bo")))       
}        
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Are you looking for type of sports or of particular events? I'm asking because your current query is looking for instances of any type of sport, e.g. for the sport marathon it returns `Boston Marathon`

Comment: I'm looking for type of sports (basketball, football, etc). basically, the user needs to let us know his favorite sports and we would look for suggestions from wikidata until our database is complete.  basically autocomplete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SAMPLE` to get a single photo for each sport. If you need all labels, but don't want to define each language separately, and require that there is only one row per sport, you can use `GROUP_CONCAT` to concatenate the labels. To bind multiple values to a variable, you can use `VALUES`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item (SAMPLE(?img) AS ?image) (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?lbl; separator=', ') AS ?label) WHERE {
  # Bind variable ?type to the types you want
  VALUES ?type { wd:Q31629 wd:Q7128792 }
  ?item wdt:P31 ?type .
  # Search only English labels
  ?item rdfs:label ?search_label .
  FILTER(LANG(?search_label) = "en")
  FILTER(STRSTARTS(lcase(?search_label), lcase("bo")))
  # Get all labels
  ?item rdfs:label ?l .
  # Produces strings like "bodybuilding (en)"
  BIND(CONCAT(STR(?l), ' (', LANG(?l), ')') AS ?lbl)
  # Get the images
  OPTIONAL {
      ?item wdt:P18 ?img .
  }
}
GROUP BY ?item
LIMIT 10
```

[Link to the above query in the Wikidata Query Service](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fitem%20%28SAMPLE%28%3Fimg%29%20AS%20%3Fimage%29%20%28GROUP_CONCAT%28DISTINCT%20%3Flbl%3B%20separator%3D%27%2C%20%27%29%20AS%20%3Flabel%29%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%3Ftype%20%7B%20wd%3AQ31629%20wd%3AQ7128792%20%7D%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20%3Ftype%20.%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fsearch_label%20.%0A%20%20FILTER%28LANG%28%3Fsearch_label%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%0A%20%20FILTER%28STRSTARTS%28lcase%28%3Fsearch_label%29%2C%20lcase%28%22bo%22%29%29%29%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fl.%0A%20%20BIND%28CONCAT%28STR%28%3Fl%29%2C%20%27%20%28%27%2C%20LANG%28%3Fl%29%2C%20%27%29%27%29%20AS%20%3Flbl%29%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP18%20%3Fimg%20.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fitem%0ALIMIT%2010)

Comment: Thanks @evsheino, this is much better than where I started. 2 issues though, the first, boxing doesn't come back in this list.  also, while I would like to get the labels in all languages, I would still like to search in one. is that possible?

Comment: I updated the query so that only English labels are searched, and only types of sports are fetched. Boxing seems to be called "boxe" in Wikidata.

Comment: That's great @evsheino.  would it be possible to make this query behave in a way to solve multiple instanceOfs. for example, could we say instanceOf sport (Q31629) OR combat sport (Q7128792) OR.. and so on? this would allow me to list the major instanceOf so the majority is covered.

Comment: Yes, you  can use `VALUES` for that - see the updated query.